# Programmatically Save Excel Add-In

Tags: vba, excel, add-in, excel-addins

I have a worksheet updated occasionally by users that is used to make an Add-In (.XLAM). The Add-In is located on a network share and users link to it. I am looking to enable users to easily update this add-in (ensuring it is marked as read only)

I have seen the article by [Ken Puls here](http://www.excelguru.ca/node/45) on deploying Excel Add-Ins however the `.SaveCopyAs` method he uses doesn’t seem to be able to accept a file type.

The `.SaveAs` method does, however when this was tried I gota message saying the file format or extension was invalid, I have tried both with .XLAM and .XLA as below.

```
DeployPath = "C:\Menu.xlam"
.SaveAs Filename:=DeployPath, ReadOnlyRecommended:=True, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLAddIn
```

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've found that sometimes I can have problems when not using the number values for FileFormat. Try using `FileFormat:=55` instead of `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLAddIn`

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve... Are you trying to save currently opened workbook (not addin) as an addin or are you trying to save addin as addin? I think you're talking about template instead addin.

Answer (score 6):

I think that you need to use (Excel 2003 and earlier)

```
ThisWorkbook.IsAddin = True
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "fredyy", xlAddIn
```

For Excel 2007+ use

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "fredyy", xlOpenXMLAddIn
```

Comment: When I try this, saving as a 2007 Macro i get the same error however when saving as a .XLA, Excel says that the file has an incorrect extension and opens the file as a regular workbook not an add-in

Comment: Thanks for your help. Running this (even in the immediate window) the file is created, when opened however Excel throws an error claiming an invalid extension or corrupted file. I tried renaming the workbook to a .ZIP file which normally works with other office 2007/10 files but also results in a corrupted file error. This worked to an extent when saving as a .XLA; the code module was there, but as it relies on a ribbon menu none actually worked. Saving from the menu works fine.

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
Dim strRawName As String
strRawName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
ThisWorkbook.IsAddin = True
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strRawName & ".xlam", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLAddIn
```